# insert data into binary tree using BST_Insert ADT function

Tags: c, insert, structure, binary-search-tree, abstract-data-type

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "BST_ADT.h"


// Structure
typedef struct
    {
        char* name;
        char* market;
        char* initial;
        float stock;
    }COMPANY;

// Prototype Delarations
void addComp    (BST_TREE* list);
void deleteComp (BST_TREE* list);
void findComp   (BST_TREE* list);
void printList (BST_TREE* list);
int  compareComp (void* Comp1, void* Comp2);
void processComp (void* dataPtr);


int main (void)
{
// Local Definitions
   BST_TREE* list;

// Statements
   list = BST_Create(compareComp);
   addComp(list);
   deleteComp(list);
   findComp (list);
   printList(list);

    return 0;
}


/*===================== addComp =========================*/

void addComp    (BST_TREE* list)
{
// Local Declarations
   COMPANY* CompPtr;
   FILE* fp;
   char fileName[25];
   char buffer [100];
   char* tempString;
// Statements

   CompPtr = (COMPANY*)malloc (sizeof (COMPANY));
   CompPtr->name = (char*) malloc(128 * sizeof(char));
   CompPtr->market = (char*) malloc(128 * sizeof(char));
   CompPtr->initial = (char*) malloc(128 * sizeof(char));
   tempString = (char*) malloc(128 * sizeof(char));

   printf("Enter the file name: ");
           gets(fileName);
           fp = fopen(fileName, "r");
           if(fp == NULL)
           {
              printf("Error cannot open the file!\n");
              exit(101);
           }
   while(fgets(buffer, 100, fp) != NULL)
        {
            if (!CompPtr)
                printf("MEmory overflow!\n"), exit(101);
            strcpy(tempString, strchr(buffer, ';') + 2);
            CompPtr->name = strtok(buffer, ";");
            sscanf(tempString, "%15s   %15s    %f ", CompPtr->market, CompPtr->initial, &(CompPtr->stock));
            BST_Insert(list, CompPtr);
        } // end while

} //addComp

/*===================== deleteComp =========================*/

void deleteComp (BST_TREE* list)
{
// local definitions
   char name[100];
   char* namePtr = (char*) malloc(128 * sizeof(char));
   namePtr = name;
// statements
   printf("Enter Company name: ");
   scanf ("%39s", namePtr);
   if (!BST_Delete (list, namePtr))
       printf("ERROR: No Company: %0\n", *namePtr);
   else
       BST_Delete(list, namePtr);
} // deleteComp


/*===================== findComp =========================*/

void findComp   (BST_TREE* list)
{
// Local Definitions
   char initial[15];
   COMPANY* CompPtr;

// Statements
   printf("Enter Company initial: ");
   scanf("%s", initial);
   CompPtr = (COMPANY*)BST_Retrieve (list, &initial);
   if (CompPtr)
      {
        printf("Company name:  %s", initial);
        printf("market name:  %s", *CompPtr->market);
        printf("company's initial:  %s", *CompPtr->initial);
        printf("stock price is:  %f", CompPtr->stock);
      } // if
   else
       printf("Company %s not in the file\n", initial);



}

/*===================== printList =========================*/

void printList (BST_TREE* list)
{
// Statements
   printf("\nCOMPANY list:\n");
   BST_Traverse(list, processComp);
   printf("end of COMPANY list\n");
   return;
} // printList


/*===================== compareComp =========================*/

int  compareComp (void* Comp1, void* Comp2)
{
// Local definitions
   COMPANY s1;
   COMPANY s2;

// Statements
   s1 = *(COMPANY*)Comp1;
   s2 = *(COMPANY*)Comp2;

   if (s1.initial < s2.initial)
       return -1;
   if (s1.initial == s2.initial)
       return 0;
   return +1;
} // compareComp

/*===================== processComp =========================*/

void processComp (void* CompPtr)
{
// Local Definitions
    COMPANY aComp;

// Statements
    aComp = *(COMPANY*) CompPtr;
    printf("%20s  %20s  %20s  %4.1f\n", *aComp.name, aComp.market, aComp.initial, aComp.stock);

    return;
} // processComp
```

In this code I'm  trying to insert data from text file into binary tree. I was able read data into CompPtr , but when i passed it in to the BST_Insert function nothing was read read into the BST tree. Why doesn't the data add into BST tree? 
thank in advance for helping.

this is my BST_Insert ADT function

```
/*===================== BST_Insert =========================*/

bool BST_Insert (BST_TREE* tree, void* DATA)
{
NODE* newPtr;

newPtr = (NODE*)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
if (!newPtr)
return false;

newPtr->right = NULL;
newPtr->left = NULL;
newPtr->dataPtr = DATA;

if (tree->count == 0)
tree->root = newPtr;
else
_insert(tree, tree->root, newPtr);

(tree->count)++;
return true;
}

/*===================== _insert =========================*/

NODE* _insert (BST_TREE* tree, NODE* root, NODE* newPtr)
{

if (!root)
return newPtr;
if (tree->compare(newPtr->dataPtr,
root->dataPtr) < 0)
{
root->left = _insert(tree, root->left, newPtr);
return root;
}
else
{
root->right = _insert(tree, root->right, newPtr);
return root;
}
return root;
}
```

after debugging for awhile, I realize that every time, the compare function, run, it return 0, due to the two parameter being equal, thus the _insert function only  add data to right of the tree but not the left side.I think what the compare function is doing is compare the same value of input,what I want is for the compare function to compare the root value and the value that I want to add in order to determine which side should the data be added in.How should i fix this problem?sorry if this code is too long, I've posted this on code review as well, but it seems more appropriate to post here since the code is not complete.

Comment: can you provide `COMPANY` structure details and data what you are getting in buffer??? Possible problem may start from here `CompPtr->name = strtok(buffer, ";");`

Comment: no, I just figured out that the problem actually come from the compare function which I have not post up there, so I'm going to edit the post